# need help in this code with get set methods

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Matrix{
    private int rowNumber;
private int colNumber;
private int val;
int [][] matrix;

public Matrix(){
    rowNumber = 0;
    colNumber = 0;
}

public Matrix(int row, int col){
    rowNumber = row;
    colNumber = col;
    Matrix obj = new Matrix();
    matrix = new int [rowNumber][colNumber];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colNumber; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter A" + (i+1) +""+ (j+1) + " : ");
            matrix [i][j] = input.nextInt();
            int val = matrix[i][j];
            obj.setElement(rowNumber,colNumber,val);
        }               
    }
    obj.display();
}

public void setElement(int r, int c, int value){
    matrix = new int [rowNumber][colNumber];
    matrix[r][c] = value;
}

public int getElement(int r, int c){
    matrix = new int [rowNumber][colNumber];
    return matrix[r][c]; 
}



    public void display(){
Matrix ex = new Matrix();
String str = "|\t";
for(int i=0; i<rowNumber; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<colNumber ;j++){
        **str += ex.getElement(i,j) + "\t";**
        }
System.out.println(str + "|");
str = "|\t";
}
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
int rowNumber;
int colNumber;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
rowNumber = input.nextInt();
System.out.println ("Enter number of columns: ");
colNumber = input.nextInt();
Matrix obj1 = new Matrix(rowNumber,colNumber);
    }
    }
```

I cannot display the required matrix. having problem in get and set methods. the program input value into an array and that value is stored in a variable. then that variable is passed as argument to the set method the setmethod takes the vaalue and put it in the array with r row and c column, all the values are stored in an array and then the display method is called in the constructor which uses the get method to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create array again in get and set and display methods. 
You are creating lot of objects unnecessarily.I have changed your code to work properly
Please use this code

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class Matrix {

    private int rowNumber;
    private int colNumber;
    int[][] matrix;

    public Matrix() {
       rowNumber = 0;
       colNumber = 0;
    }

   public Matrix(int row, int col) {
       rowNumber = row;
       colNumber = col;
       matrix = new int[rowNumber][colNumber];

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       for (int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < colNumber; j++) {
              System.out.println("Enter A" + (i + 1) + "" + (j + 1) + " : ");
              setElement(i, j, input.nextInt());
          }
       }
       display();
    }

     public void setElement(int r, int c, int value) {
        matrix[r][c] = value;
     }

     public int getElement(int r, int c) {
        return matrix[r][c];
      }

     public void display() {

         String str = "|\t";
         for (int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < colNumber; j++) {
                  str += getElement(i, j) + "\t";
             }
             System.out.println(str + "|");
             str = "|\t";
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int rowNumber;
      int colNumber;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
      rowNumber = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter number of columns: ");
      colNumber = input.nextInt();
      Matrix obj1 = new Matrix(rowNumber, colNumber);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Ive tried this as well but it shows 0 in output. or most of the times it gives arrayindexoutofbounds exception

Answer (score 1):

Your code had several `NullPointerException`s, basically because you were creating new `Matrix` objects using an empty constructor and then trying to set the matrix' properties from there, which means there was no matrix created inside your empty constructor, thus causing it to point to null.

Try this instead (I also used Prabhaker's answer here):

```
public Matrix(int row, int col){
    rowNumber = row;
    colNumber = col;
    matrix = new int[rowNumber][colNumber];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colNumber; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter A" + (i + 1) + "" + (j + 1) + " : ");
            matrix[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            int val = matrix[i][j];
            setElement(rowNumber - 1, colNumber - 1, val);
        }
    }
    display();
}

public void setElement(int r, int c, int value) {
    matrix[r][c] = value;
}

public int getElement(int r, int c) {
    return matrix[r][c];
}

public void display() {
    String str = "|\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colNumber; j++) {
            str += getElement(i, j) + "\t";
        }
        System.out.println(str + "|");
        str = "|\t";
    }
}`
```